# My interval in the y-axis changes

Tags: r

I need help with this issue.
When I plot out this exponential distribution of this code:

```
x<-runif(100)
y<--log(1-x)
hist(y)
```

I get this plot:
[image]

But when I add the exponential curve on my histogram, the interval for the y-values seems to be divided with 100?

The only difference in the code are these 2 new lines:

```
hist(y,prob=TRUE)
curve(dexp(x, rate = 0.8), col = 2, lty = 2, lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Im a beginnner to R, so would appreciate if someone could help me out with this issue. I want the second plot to also have the same interval as the first plot.

I think the interval for the first plot is the correcct one, since in the first line of my code we generate 100 values x. So the sum of the y-values of our "bars" should be equal to 100, right? Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: You get probability densities instead of count if you set `prob = TRUE`.

Comment: Okay so what do you suggest?

Comment: I'd recommend keeping it as-is, using a probability density rather than a count. The bars will sum to 1, as will the area under the density curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw a blank density histogram on top of the regular one and consequently add the curve:

```
hist(y, border = "black")
par(new = TRUE) # allows us to draw new plot on top of first one
hist(y, probability = TRUE, 
     axes = FALSE, border = "white", 
     xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "")
curve(dexp(x, rate = 0.8), 
      col = 2, lty = 2, 
      lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Note that the plot looks different because of the randomness in `runif()`.

Comment: Probably `border = "gray50"` would be better than `border = "white"` for seeing the bars.

Comment: @Biggiez see update, you need to set `border = "black"` for the first plot.

Comment: Oh okay now I see them, thanks very much!
I have another question if you wouldnt mind...since im also new to statistics (first course): 

Im not certain of what our x-axis and y-axis represents? So the x-axis is the distribution of our values from our distribution function? And the y-axis is the frequency of these values? Am I thinking correct? So the sum of the frequency of each bar will equal to 100, since we have 100 values?

Comment: Okay thanks.. I want to change the name of our x-axis from "y" to "distribution values" .. but when I edit xlab = "Distribution of our values", This text becomes overlayed on the letter "y" . Do you know how I remove the letter "y" from the x-axis?

Comment: I was just wondering one last thing about the line "par(new = T)".
What does the T stand for? Is it "True" ? How did this 1 new line of code manage to change the interval of our new plot to the old one? Im curious..

Comment: stands for `TRUE` indeed, it  `allows us to draw new plot on top of first one`,